# How to use subprocess to send commands to a command line program?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to understand how to use subprocess, but I'm having a hard time.  I have a program called **ReadWriteProprerty.py**.  Normally, I'd open a terminal window, execute the program...

```
python ReadWriteProperty.py
```

Then I can interact with the program through the terminal and it will print outputs.  The next command I'd call is read with proper arguments...

```
> read 192.168.92.68 analogInput 2 presentValue
```

and the current temperature is printed to the terminal window...

```
> 78.5
```

So, with subprocess I'm trying to execute this **ReadWriteProperty.py** from another driver program, let's call it **driver.py**.  Then, I want to execute the **read** command with it's arguments and get the output.  Basically, I need **driver.py** to be a short program that interacts with **ReadWriteProperty.py** through a subproccess or os.system.  I just need it to do what I normally do manually through the terminal.  Can anyone explain how I might do this?  I've been trying to use **Popen**, but I don't know how to call the **read** command once I have a process open. Thanks in advance for any help.

**P.S.** obviously the ideal solution would be to re-write **ReadWriteProperty.py** as a module and import it, but that causes a much more complicated problem of its own.

Comment: can you pipe the output of `ReadWriteProprerty` ?

Comment: So does `python ReadWriteProperty.py` need to still be running when you call `read 192.168.92.68 analogInput 2 presentValue` or can you just run the commands in series?

Comment: You can't call them in series.  That's the main issue is that it has to still be running in the terminal.